# I tried creating a small widget application but i get the Error:Not a signal or slot declaration

Tags: c++, qt

```
class TDF : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit TDF(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~TDF();


private slots:
    void on_umwelt_clicked();

    void on_regional_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_autofahrt_clicked();

    void on_flugzeug_clicked();

    void on_bestell_clicked();

    int anzahl=3;

private:
    Ui::TDF *ui;
};

#endif // TDF_H
```

This is my header. I tried starting the application, but it keeps saying Error: Not a signal or slot declaration.
Please help me :(

Comment: I don't believe the error is in the code presented. My guess is you improperly called connect()

Answer (score 0):

Solved the Problem. Int anzahl is not a slot but was in private slots as Seen above

Comment: That is wierd. I don't usually pay that much attention to this. Although with that said in a lot of my cases I use PIMPIL so there usually are not many data members exposed in the public interface.